# Watchkit app fails to launch only on ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store-connect

I'm trying to submit an app to TestFlight, but have been rejected twice for this reason:

> 2.3 Details
>
> However, we attempted to review your app but were unable to install
>   the app on iPad. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the
>   Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on an
>   iPad.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to verify that it
>   contains only the attributes required for your app features or the
>   attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes
>   specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are required
>   and false if they must not be present on the device.

When I try to launch the app on the ipad simulator, I'm getting the error:

```
Oct  2 11:32:04 exploiter.local com.apple.dt.Xcode[59574] <Error>: Error 

Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x7fe30acc1950 
{Error=WatchKitTwoAppMissingExtension, ErrorDescription=WatchKit 2 app at /Users/yair/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1E3162E3-A525-4B7E-B36C-4EC17B4C7A96/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.sq7Y13/extracted/MA.app/Watch/MA WatchKit App.app 
is missing its app extension.}
```

Has anyone seen this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure this will help someone as I believe this is an xcode bug.

What happens is that turning on the HealthKit capability on the Apple Watch extension adds a value `healthkit`to the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities array of that same target.

For some strange reason that value prevents the app from launching properly on any iPad device. Manually removing the `healthkit` value from the Apple Watch extension target plist fixed the issue and submission was successful.

Also, if after deleting the value you see a warning on that screen you can ignore it. The app will deploy and install without issues.

Comment: This helped immensely! Please submit this bug to Apple!

Answer (score 0):

Apple Watch Apps (WatchKit Extension) is designed to be a companion to the iPhone & only work with iPhone properly. may be there is a workaround to connect it to iPad (not in my knowledge) but Apps will not work as you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you, for your reply. According to this documentation entry https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW13 all extensions must be compatible with all iOS devices or else they will be rejected by the app store. You are correct in that watchKit functionality is not available on the iPad, but the binary will be tested by apple on iPad devices, and if they don't run you'll get a rejection like I did